JPA OneToMany Relationship: Foreign Key Not Persisted in Child Table
I'm encountering an issue when persisting a parent JPA entity that has a OneToMany relationship with its child entities. When saving the parent entity using EclipseLink, both the parent and child entities are saved to their respective tables, but the foreign key in the child table that links back to the parent is left null, breaking the relationship in the database.
To be specific, the problem is with the application_address table. I can't get the configuration right between TblApplicationAdress and TblApplicationMembership so that JPA saves the application_membership_id foreign key link into the application_address table. (For context, an application contains one membership which contains many addresses.)
Below are the details of my setup:

Database: PostgreSQL 14
Java Version: Java 11
Annotations: Using Lombok's @Getter and @Setter
Persistence: EclipseLink with JPA

Tables:
create table application
(
    application_id                bigserial primary key,
    application_membership_id     bigint references application_membership,
    application_reference_number  varchar,
    -- other fields...
);

create table application_membership
(
    application_membership_id   bigserial primary key,
    membership_reference_number varchar,
    -- other fields...
);

create table application_address
(
    application_address_id    bigserial primary key,
    application_membership_id bigint references application_membership,
    address_type_code         varchar,
    address_line1_number      varchar,
    -- other fields...
);

JPA Entities:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplication {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_id")
    private Long applicationId;

    @Column(name = "application_reference_number")
    private String applicationReferenceNumber;

    // Other fields...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_membership_id", referencedColumnName = "application_membership_id")
    private TblApplicationMembership applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_membership", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplicationMembership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_membership_id")
    private Long applicationMembershipId;

    @Column(name = "membership_reference_number")
    private String membershipReferenceNumber;

    // Other fields...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<TblApplicationAddress> applicationAddressesByApplicationMembershipId;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_address", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplicationAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_address_id")
    private Long applicationAddressId;

    @Column(name = "address_type_code")
    private String addressTypeCode;

    @Column(name = "address_line1_number")
    private String addressLine1Number;

    // Other fields...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_membership_id", referencedColumnName = "application_membership_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private TblApplicationMembership applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId;
}

Service Layer:
tblApplication = applicationDataService.save(tblApplication);

Data Service:
public T save(T t) throws DataServiceException {
    try {
        t = em.merge(t);
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        return t;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DataServiceException("Error BaseDataService.save...", ex);
    }
}

I’ve tried using @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagedReference, and cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, as suggested in these discussions:

JPA Persist parent and child with one to many relationship
Spring Data JPA Foreign Key in Child not persisting

Unfortunately, these approaches haven't resolved the issue. If I can't get this working, I may have to manually save the parent entity first, then assign the foreign key ID to the child entity before saving it, but I'd prefer to avoid this workaround due to the complexity and size of the object structure.
Question:
What could be causing the foreign key in the child table to remain null when persisting these entities? Is there a configuration or annotation I might be missing, or is there a better way to ensure the foreign key is correctly set when saving the parent entity?

Is the parent backreference set in the child entity?
TblApplicationMembership membership = new TblApplicationMembership(); TblApplicationAddress address = new TblApplicationAddress(); address.setApplicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId(membership); membership.addApplicationAddress(address);
This could be handled in the parent like this:
public void addApplicationAddress(TblApplicationAddress address) {         address.setApplicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId(this);         this.applicationAddressesByApplicationMembershipId.add(address);     }

Yes @Technobabel. See the applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId field in TblApplicationAddress (the child) back linked to the applicationAddressesByApplicationMembershipId field in TblApplicationMembership (the parent). I'm trying to avoid writing the manual code you suggested I'd rather configure the JPA classes to automatically save the foreign key - this will be much cleaner on account of the complex structure I have (the above is just a snippet of the structure).

The problem here is not JPA, but your object are probably deserialized from jackson, so not managed by JPA. "merge" is just the trick to make your entity managed, but it's not recrusive, seem similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269527/recursive-upserts-with-hibernate-jpa

I could not find the resolution I wanted, so resorted to a more manual approach.
Firstly, it was extremely important to set the cascade to CascadeType.ALL on the parent JPA classes.
Secondly, the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference made no difference, so I removed the annotations.
Here are the updated JPA entities:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplication {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_id")
    private Long applicationId;

    @Column(name = "application_reference_number")
    private String applicationReferenceNumber;

    // Other fields...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_membership_id", referencedColumnName = "application_membership_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TblApplicationMembership applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_membership", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplicationMembership {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_membership_id")
    private Long applicationMembershipId;

    @Column(name = "membership_reference_number")
    private String membershipReferenceNumber;

    // Other fields...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<TblApplicationAddress> applicationAddressesByApplicationMembershipId;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_address", schema = "obd")
public class TblApplicationAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "application_address_id")
    private Long applicationAddressId;

    @Column(name = "address_type_code")
    private String addressTypeCode;

    @Column(name = "address_line1_number")
    private String addressLine1Number;

    // Other fields...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_membership_id", referencedColumnName = "application_membership_id")
    private TblApplicationMembership applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId;
}

And here is the manual code in the service layer I was trying to avoid
tblApplication = applicationDataService.save(tblApplication);
Collection<TblApplicationAddress> addresses = tblApplicationMembership.getApplicationAddressesByApplicationMembershipId();
for (TblApplicationAddress entity : addresses) {
    entity.setApplicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId(tblApplicationMembership);
}
tblApplication = applicationDataService.save(tblApplication);

I am certain there is a way to configure the JPA classes to avoid this manual workaround, but if anyone finds themselves under time pressure, and needing a solution, this will do it.

You don't need to save the tblApplication twice in this code - only once at the end should be enough. And the code (once you added the cascade merge option included in "ALL") shows that it isn't a JPA or entity model problem, but an issue with your Jackson/JSON unmarshalling, such that the  applicationMembershipByApplicationMembershipId references aren't set. If you don't have annotations, you WILL get recursion errors when you serialize this model from JPA into JSON. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion but maybe use @JsonIdentityInfo

Thanks for that - I'll need to look deeper into the unmarshalling, but the JsonManagedReference and JsonBackRefernece which your linked article suggests didn't work. I'm certain I'm implementing it incorrectly somehow, but I haven't been able to work out why. That is why I have implemented a "hacky" approach. It does need 2 saves - the 1st saves to the application_address table with a null in the application_address.application_membership_id, and the 2nd sets the application_address.application_membership_id. Ugly code, but working code.

That was why I sent the link - you are missing the JsonIdentityInfo which will allow your JSON marshaller (jackson) to put in the entity in the circular relationship instead of just nulling it out, so it can find the built entity when unmarshalling it into your object. You'll have to look at what JSON is being sent - it needs to have the references in the JSON data. Work out what your 'GET' endpoints give you as you'll need to use that as a starting point for what is required on the PUT/POST
